# Arrastrar ventana modal de Bootstrap con el mouse

Tags: bootstrap

Estoy usando una ventana modal de Bootstrap  ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se pueda arrastrar con el mouse la ventana modal ya que se queda estática?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="Modal Window ">
  <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Modals con Twitter Bootstrap</h2>
    <div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>Cabecera de la ventana</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Texto de la ventana</h4>
        <p>Mas texto en la ventana.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Abrir</a>
    </p>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola estimado, que deseas mover ?? el dialogo que no este centrado o arrastrar el modal con el mouse ? Proba con esto 
  $("#myModal").draggable({
      handle: ".modal-header"
  });

Comment: @Santi92 hola brother lo que deseo hacer es arrastrar la ventana con el mouse efectivamente, ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo por que no he podido y no hay casi informacion?

Comment: te sirvio la respuesta ?

Comment: @Santi92 si amigo funcionó gracias por la ayuda, no m funcionaba por que me faltaba una libreria de jquery :::: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Ahh perfecto, cualquier otra consulta , no dudes en formular otra pregunta en SOes. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con `jquery` puedes usar la función `draggable`, la misma permite mover elementos utilizando el mouse, para tu modal **example**  el código sería:

```
$("#example").draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
});
```

Para más documentación puedes visiar https://jqueryui.com/draggable/. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Revisa este ejemplo donde usa lo que te han comentado del draggable de jquery:
http://jsfiddle.net/raving/gL6zodx7/

Saludos